# Think i installed ubuntu wrongly

Tags: 14.04

My windows was not working so i erased everything and installed ubuntu (no dual boot). When i open my computer ot dhows 1.try using ubuntu 2.install ubuntu. I selected install ubuntu ,after instaling it shows restart now. When i restart, it shows again 1.try using ubuntu 2.install ubuntu..
What is this happening?? I cannot understand .when i open ubuntu grub opens automatically. When i place command "exit" then some options come saying 1.try ubuntu without instaling 2.install ubuntu on hdd 3.advsnce option 4.help
(Installed ubuntu using usb) what should i do now? Is there any way to install ubuntu or  go to boot menu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not remove the dvd or usb stick? Seems the most logical answer to this. The try/install is only on the dvd or usb.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the installation media and you are good to go :)